# how to prevent same product adding multiple times to cart when I want my visitor to directly go to checkout

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Let say someone decides to buy my product and click on the buy now option and reached my checkout page. But for some reason he/she didn't buy it.
But after sometime he/she made his mind to purchase the product but when they click on buy know button the product price get doubles because the product is added a second time in the cart.
As i am not giving access to the cart page to my visitor so they can't modify there cart.

Is there anyway with which I can prevent the same product adding a second time in cart.
I don't want the min maximum plugin because it doesn't prevent from adding same product  multiple time. It just shows  a notification that the max amount is 1.

I just don't want the same product to be addded twice in the cart no matter what.

I tried this code:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );
function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

But after adding it I am not able to add a second product into my cart.
As I have added a order bump in my checkout page but when i tried to add it it replaced the main product.

Comment: Hiding cart wont prevent ?add-to-cart=25&quantity=999 so keep that in mind ;) Use the solution below to force only 1 qty per item

Answer (score 0):

You can force a single purchase of a given product from Edit Product > Product Data > Inventory > Sold Individually

No code needed